In SQL, what do I add below to average the depths by year?
The code before works just fine, but I can't figure out the next step at all. Next, I want all locations averaged by year and output a new column called annual_average.
My dataset is here: https://mgs-maine.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/maine-snow-survey-data/explore?showTable=true.
SELECT  
  SITE_NAME,
  SURVEY_YEAR,
  AVG(DEPTH) AS snow_depth,
FROM `capstone-433319.maine_snow_survey.snow_data`
WHERE
  SURVEY_YEAR>=1984 AND
  DEPTH>=0 AND
  SITE_NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  
  SURVEY_YEAR,
  SITE_NAME
ORDER BY
  SITE_NAME


Try using window function to count average value by SITE_NAME
SELECT  
  "SITE_NAME" ,
  "SURVEY_YEAR" ,
  AVG("DEPTH") AS snow_depth,
  round(AVG("DEPTH") over (partition by "SITE_NAME"),2) as annual_average
FROM maine_snow_survey_data
WHERE
  "SURVEY_YEAR">=1984 AND
  "DEPTH">=0 AND
  "SITE_NAME" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  
  "SURVEY_YEAR",
  "SITE_NAME",
  "DEPTH"
ORDER BY
  "SITE_NAME";


I ran that code after updating the source table name, and it gave me the oddest error: No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY >= ANY. This is weird because that hasn't been an issue until now. Do I need to cast something to another data type somewhere?

try,
AVG(DEPTH) OVER (PARTITION BY SITE_NAME, SURVEY_YEAR) AS annual_average

to calculate the average depth for each unique combination of SITE_NAME and SURVEY_YEAR.
SELECT  
  SITE_NAME,
  SURVEY_YEAR,
  AVG(DEPTH) AS snow_depth,
  AVG(DEPTH) OVER (PARTITION BY SITE_NAME, SURVEY_YEAR) AS annual_average
FROM Maine_Snow_Survey_Data
WHERE
  SURVEY_YEAR>=1984 AND
  DEPTH>=0 AND
  SITE_NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  
  SURVEY_YEAR,
  SITE_NAME
ORDER BY
  SITE_NAME

